# Recent posts not showing up on Jekyll Pixyll theme

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I am working on a a personal webpage and I have the latest Pixyll release forked to my repo. I have made changes to `_posts/2014-06-08-pixyll-has-pagination.md` and included the following attributes in the header

```
published: true
permalink: /test/
```

When I direct my url to `webpage/test/`, I am able to see the blog post but I am not able to see it as part of recent posts in my homepage. My `index.html` is as follows:

```
---
layout: default
---
{% assign posts_count = (paginator.posts | size) %}

<div class="home">
  {% if posts_count > 0 %}
    <div class="posts">
      {% for post in paginator.posts %}
        <div class="post py3">
          <p class="post-meta">{{ post.date | date: site.date_format }}</p>
          <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: site.baseurl }}" class="post-link"><h3 class="h1 post-title">{{ post.title }}</h3></a>
          <p class="post-summary">
            {% if post.summary %}
              {{ post.summary }}
            {% else %}
              {{ post.excerpt }}
            {% endif %}
          </p>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% include pagination.html %}
  {% else %}
    <h1 class='center'>{{ site.text.index.coming_soon }}</h3>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: is it really ruby-on rails related question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's how [pagination](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/) works.

You have five posts :

```
_posts
├── 2015-07-11-announcing-pixyll-version-2.md
├── 2014-06-11-welcome-to-pixyll.markdown
├── 2014-06-10-see-pixyll-in-action.md
├── 2014-06-09-so-what-is-jekyll.md
└── 2014-06-08-pixyll-has-pagination.md
```

Your `site.pagination` is set to `4`.

Your **blog index** will show **first 4 posts** and **page 2** will show **5th post** (`2014-06-08-pixyll-has-pagination.md`)

**There is no problem here.**

Note: In your _config.yml

- remove `=======` on line 1
- change `github_username:lordlabakdas` to `github_username: lordlabakdas` space after colon
- change `twitter_username:siddugan` to `twitter_username: siddugan` space after colon